Domain DNS settings for email
My email is hosted on a server, IP x.x.x.x.
I'm using domain example.com to display a website. My domain is  IP y.y.y.y.
Current settings:
A     mail.example.com    x.x.x.x
A     webmail.example.com    x.x.x.x
A     example.com         y.y.y.y
MX    example.com         mx4.blabla.com
MX    example.com         mx3.blabla.com
MX    example.com         mx2.blabla.com
MX    example.com         mx1.blabla.com
TXT   example.com         v=spf1 include:spf.blabla.com -all 

The current status of the email is: not working.
I need to keep example.com at y.y.y.y and email hosted at x.x.x.x.
How can I go about fixing the issue?

Only MX records (and TXT SPF) are relevant for e-mail. The bare A record is not. Why email is not working is impossible to tell from the information in your question.

What you're saying here is that all your mail is going to, and coming from, blabla.com. You want it to go to, and come from, mail.example.com. What you need is
MX    example.com        mail.example.com  10
TXT   example.com        v=spf1 +mx -all

You can keep mx[1..4].blabla.com as a backup mail server if blabla.com has agreed to be your mail server - if you're paying them for that service - in which case your TXT record becomes v=spf1 +mx include:spf.blabla.com -all, but if you're not keeping them as mail servers they should not be included in your MX records.
